# Unable to create & update category while able to find existing category programmatically in Sitecore commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-catalog, minion

In `Sitecore Commerce 9.3`, I'm attempting to import and sync categories, but I am not able to create or update categories programmatically while getting info for existing categories via `_getCategoryCommand` as shown on screenshot but `_createCategoryCommand` is neither throwing any exception nor creating categories.

No error logs were found. When `_createCategoryCommand` executes it never comes to the next line.

i.e. `category.Name = parameter.Name`.

I've read & followed this article - https://hachweb.wordpress.com/2018/09/09/sitecore-xc-9-0-2-walkthrough-of-creating-your-own-product-importer-with-various-pitfalls/

[image]

Comment: Is this only on creating category or do you face the same issue if you create a Catalog? Found a different code that casts it to a category after creating category = await _createCategoryCommand.Process(CurrentContext, catalog.Id, categoryModel.Name,
            categoryModel.DisplayName, categoryModel.Description) as Category;   and last question is your catalogus you are refuring to existing?

Comment: Please add code lines in place of Image for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below methods to create and update the category. You can modify the code accordingly to check the existing category.

1. Find existing category -

   ```
   using Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog;

   using System.Linq;

   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   public async Task<Category> FindCategoryByName(string categoryName)
   {
        // Get all categories
        var categories = await _commerceCommander.GetEntities<Category>(context.CommerceContext, CommerceEntity.ListName<Category>(), 0, int.MaxValue);

       // Find the category by name
       var category = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.DisplayName.Equals(categoryName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

      return category;
     }
   ```
2. Create a category -

   ```
   using Sitecore.Commerce.Core;
   using Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog;
   using System;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   public async Task CreateCategory(string categoryName, string parentCategoryName = "")
   {
      // Assuming you have a Commerce Engine instance initialized

      // Create a new category
      var category = new Category
    {
        DisplayName = categoryName,
        ParentCategoryList = new ListEntityComponent
        {
            Items = new List<string> { parentCategoryName }
        }
    };

    // Add the category to the catalog
    await _commerceCommander.Pipeline<ICreateCategoryPipeline>().Run(new CreateCategoryArgument(category), context);
   }
   ```
3. Update a Category

   ```
   using Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   public async Task UpdateCategory(string categoryId, string newCategoryName)
   {
      // Load the category
      var category = await _commerceCommander.GetEntity<Category>(context.CommerceContext, categoryId);

      if (category != null)
      {
         // Update the category name
         category.DisplayName = newCategoryName;

         // Save the changes
         await _commerceCommander.Pipeline<IUpdateCategoryPipeline>().Run(category, context.CommerceContext);
      }
   }
   ```